# SQL выбор строк с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: php, sql

Почему при выполнении запроса:

```
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coments WHERE id_foto='$id'",$db);
```

выводится только одна строка из таблицы? (имеются 2 строки с одинаковым значением id_foto).

Comment: а экранировать данные, вставляя их в запрос, не надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стесняюсь спросить, как вы выводите поля?
Через

```
$vuvod= mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

**ИЛИ так:**

```
while(mysql_fetch_array($res)){
   $vuvod= mysql_fetch_array($res);
}
```

Если второй вариант, тогда сделайте следующие:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM `coments` GROUP BY id_foto WHERE `id_foto`='".$id."'";
```

После чего, скопируйте то, что выведет и выполните запрос через phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Уберите [группировку](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html).

Comment: извиняюсь, скинул не тот код. Вот так у меня все было изначально: $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `coments` WHERE `id_foto`='$id'",$db); НО это не работает

Comment: Значит нужно проверить что передается в $id, и выполнить запрос с этим значением из консоли.

Answer (score 0):

1.GROUP BY используется после условия WHERE!

2.Чтобы выполнилась ваша задача Вам нужно убрать ORDER BY, а также убрать и WHERE-условие.

Ваш запрос на выборку всех полей таков:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments`
```